# NGINX as a reverse proxy for outgoing requests?

Tags: http, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I understand that NGINX is intended to be setup to load balance traffic for web servers, or as a proxy for incoming requests.
I'm wondering if it can be used as a reverse proxy for outgoing requests to a web server that I don't own. In other words I'd like to know if I can setup NGINX on one of our servers, and configure a dns entry such that all traffic (either from a specific host on my LAN, or all hosts on my LAN) destined for a specific website (let's say https://yahoo.com) are routed to the NGINX service -> yahoo.com web server. And responses from yahoo.com are returned to the NGINX server and forwarded back to the original client that made the request.

I need to funnel all requests to yahoo.com through a proxy and have the proxy act as an intermediary so requests to yahoo.com appear to come from the proxy's IP, and responses from yahoo.com are returned to the original requester on LAN.

Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how NGINX can be used? Are there better open source/free reverse proxy options? I've tried to set  this up with other reverse-proxy options but they don't seem to work how I need, or allow the original client to browse target website, moreso it only works for specific singular requests.

Is a "reverse proxy" not what I need? Is there some other name for what I am trying to achieve?

Any information is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You'd need a regular web proxy for this. Take a look at squid3 for a general idea.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Super simple I setup squid on one of my debian EC2 instances and it worked like a charm. I appreciate the tip

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tobyd, squid was exactly what I needed - a regular proxy, worked perfectly.
Thank you